# PM2 with ES module. Error: ERR_REQUIRE_ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, pm2

My **package.json** file looks something like this:

```
{
...
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "devStart": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env dev --watch",
    "prodStart": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env prod --watch",
    "reload": "pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js",
    "stop": "pm2 stop ecosystem.config.js",
    "end": "pm2 delete ecosystem.config.js"
  },
...
}
```

I have activated ES modules by `"type": "module",` as you see.

And the **ecosystem.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "app1",
    script : "./app.js",
    env_production: {
       NODE_ENV: "production"
    },
    env_development: {
       NODE_ENV: "development"
    }
  }]
}
```

So, when I run the script `npm run devStart` an error occurs.

> File ecosystem.config.js malformated

> code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'

*It works when I just remove the `"type": "module"` part from config file.*

How can I solve this?

`node -v : v16.13.0`

`pm2 -v : 5.1.2`

Comment: What does your importing module syntax look like?

Comment: It's old style importing there `require()`. It seems PM2 doesn't support ES Modules yet.
But I find a temporary solution for this, here: https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/293

Comment: You will have very limited success, if any, mixing and matching module formats. You should stick with CommonJS.

Answer (score 13):

Rename `ecosystem.config.js` to `ecosystem.config.cjs`

Comment: Then I get: [PM2][ERROR] File ecosystem.config.js not found

Comment: @vladaman include config's filename in the command line: pm2 start ecosystem.config.cjs

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the better way to  avoid this error  is  creating the ecosystem.config.js outside the app directory that PM2 couldn't see the package.json file. I could  run my  ecosystem.config only  use this way and also fixed  a path  for running script. Example :

```
module.exports = { 
 apps : [{
    name   : "nuxt3_app",
    script : "myApp/.output/server/index.mjs",
    interpreter: "node",
    env: {
       DATABASE_URL: "mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/db"
    },

  }]
}
```